# Test Run deployment issue: 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC'

Tags: oracle, automation, coded-ui-tests

I just configured the code on my machine. (VS2013 Premium) and I am not able to run any of the test case because of one following error :

> "Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module
>   'Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC' directly or indirectly referenced by the
>   test container
>   'e:\cs\qa_automation\all_team_current_automation\international\lda_automation\bin\debug\lda_automation.dll' was not found."

It is an Oracle version issue or what ? Can anybody guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioned dll is part of Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC). You need to install Oracle client software called [32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) 
with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html)

This should add Oracle support components for Visual Studio and solve your issue.

Comment: The managed ODP.NET you don't habe to install. Simply put a copy of the dll to yor application folder

Comment: Thanks @Stefan Yordanov , I'll try this and update .. :)